# Get usedrange of Microsoft Graph API doesn't work

Tags: excel, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get values that are stored in Excel cells using the method Get usedrange (see the page below), but it doesn't work.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/worksheet_usedrange

The following error response is returned.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "InvalidArgument",
    "message": "引数が正しくない、不足している、または形式が不適切です。", //The argument is incorrect, missing, or the format is inappropriate.
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "dcff76b5-9bc6-4a01-b99f-853b9430ef0d",
        "date": "2017-05-01T09:01:15"
    }
}
```

}

I tried GET (as opposed to POST) with the same request URL on a trial ......it is mysterious that sometimes were time out, but sometimes all cell data was returned without timeout (result, the browser hung up).

I'd be very appreciated it if I could get any advise from anyone who encounters the same phenomenon or knows how to avoid it.

--

Additional Notes:

-Excel Data

[image]

-Execution result in Graph Explorer (original method, POST)
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01PYKTZAO2B65SCU2UDJCKMKFWJEEDRNLQ/workbook/worksheets('Sheet1')/UsedRange()

[image]

-Additional Information - Result when use GET in the same URL
[image]

Comment: Here's an example of usedRange in the graph explorer - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/drive/items/01CNPZDUYJI5OMBJJSL5EI3YIOG4HRKEGN/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/usedRange&method=GET&version=v1.0 .  Can you paste your request URL so we can compare?

Comment: @dan-silver-microsoft Thank you for your reply! I've added the request URL and some. Please see the Additional Notes in the post. Thank you!

Comment: The actual request is over GET verb. The doc showed POST incorrectly and has been fixed. Does it still timeout? Seems like a small used range based in the image shown and it shouldn't time out for that reason.

Comment: I executed again refering the doc above.
Originally, as described in the response section of the doc, I think that only meta information such as the number of cells will be returned. However, all the data in the cell of the use range is returned.
In the case of small data, response is returned, but in the case of a large amount of data which it is supposed to perform, it takes more than 30 seconds and sometimes time-out occurs.
Also, I think it seems rare to attach Request Body in Get request, is the description of the above doc correct?

Answer (score 0):

The author left a comment saying that they only expected metadata (such as the number of cells), but received all of the data in the range.

You can filter which information you'd like back like so:

```
/usedRange?$select=columnCount,rowCount,address,addressLocal,cellCount,columnIndex,rowIndex
```

(Doing this prevents the query from returning the actual data from the cells because it omits things like numberFormat, text, formulas, formulasLocal, formulasR1C1, valueTypes, and values.)