# Microsoft Graph Excel API - request not working with multiple ranges

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Can we access specific cell values from multiple ranges using a single Microsoft Graph request?

For example:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{file-id}/workbook/worksheets('{id}')/Range(address='e10:e11,c58:c59')`

If  I request only one range then I am getting the expected result. If I use the query above to get two specific ranges is not working:

```
"error": { 
    "code": "InvalidArgument", 
    "message": "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.", 
    "innerError": { 
         "request-id": "1d3d0a3c-cf6f-4f0c-8e84-c65ff80cd020", 
          "date": "2017-07-25T14:13:11" 
     } 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?  Are you not getting values?  Are you getting the wrong values? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Hi @JoshuaDrake I am getting an below error message: "error": {
        "code": "InvalidArgument",
        "message": "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "1d3d0a3c-cf6f-4f0c-8e84-c65ff80cd020",
            "date": "2017-07-25T14:13:11"
        }
    }

Comment: Though a different language, have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749240/get-usedrange-of-microsoft-graph-api-doesnt-work

Comment: Can you add that range with a name and then simply pass the name in?

Comment: Hi @JoshuaDrake I dont think passing the name will work may be the way I am passing two range is not right . for Eg : Instead of this e10:e11,c58:c59 it could be [e10:e11,c58:c59] or [e10:e11],[c58:c59] but I have tried other combinations as well and its not working

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're attempting to use Graph in the same way VBA can be used to [refer to multiple ranges](http://Refer%20to%20Multiple%20Ranges) (i.e. `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:D9,G9:H16,B14:D18")`). This isn't model isn't supported by Graph.

Instead you'll need to pull each range using a separate `GET` request:

```
GET workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/range(address='e10:e11')
GET workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/range(address='c58:c59')
```

Comment: yeah, But i dont want to send get request that many number of times Thats why I was asking if there is any other way .